# EXCEL VBA: Format text after Point in each Cell

Tags: excel, vba

I have thousands of cells with a reference (1 to 4 characters) after the last Point ( . ) of the sentence inside the cell. the 1-4 reference character are not in a particular order.

For example in a cell I have:

|This is a text. L|

or

|This is an other text. IL|

After I select a range of cellule manualy, I would like to have a VBA macro to
Select after the point any character present, if cell empty do nothing and next
Make it Bold, Red and superscript
Move to the next cell and do again until the end

I have tried

```
Sub BoldCellsLastWord()
lc = Right(ActiveCell, 1)
  With Selection.Font
        .Color = -16776961
        .TintAndShade = 0
       Selection.Font.Superscript = True
       Selection.Font.Bold = True
  End With
End Sub
```

but the whole sentence is getting formatted

What I do wrong ?

in advance thanks for your help

Comment: You need to find the position of the dot and then use `Characters` property.

Answer (score 1):

works for manual start

```
Sub test2()
    Dim n As Integer, i As Integer, counter As Integer
    Dim text As String
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    n = ws.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column).Characters.Count
    text = Selection.Value
    
    For i = 1 To n
        If Mid(text, i, 1) = "." Then
            ws.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column).Characters(i, n - i + 1).Font.Superscript = True  ' with dot
            'ws.Cells(Selection.Row, Selection.Column).Characters(i+1, n - i + 1).Font.Superscript = True  ' without dot
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

if you want to run code automaticly you should create `worksheet.selectionchange` event and paste

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target.Column = n Then ' column index where you want do superscript
        test2 ' or place here code
    End If
End Sub
```

it will work for any selected range in wanted column. You shouldn't do loop through whole sheet by macro started in `selectionchange` event. You can do some form with start button

Comment: You could use `Instr` to avoid the loop.

Comment: thank you for your input to my question  @Tomasz I will go with EEC VBA

Answer (score 1):

This proposed solution:

- Works with the `Selection` range *(change as required)*
- Validates if the `Cell` contains a `Formula`
- Validates if the `Cell` has `Contents`
- Validates if the `Cell` contains a `.` using `InStrRev` to ensure it uses the last `.`
- Formats the contents as required

…

```
Sub Format_Text_In_Cells()
Dim Rng As Range, Cll As Range
Dim bLen As Byte, bPos As Byte

    Set Rng = Selection
    For Each Cll In Rng.Cells
        With Cll
            
            If Not (.HasFormula) Then           'Validates if cells contains a formula
            
                bLen = Len(.Value)                  'Get length of cell contents
                bPos = InStrRev(.Value, ".")        'Get position of last "."
                If bPos > 0 And bPos < bLen Then
                
                    'With .Characters(Start:=1 + bPos, Length:=bLen).Font   'Use this line to exclude the `.`
                    With .Characters(Start:=bPos, Length:=bLen).Font        'Use this line to include the `.`
                    
                        Rem Format Cell Contents
                        .FontStyle = "Bold"
                        .Superscript = True
                        .Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    
    End With: End If: End If: End With: Next

    End Sub
```

Cells `[A5]` and `[A8]` contain formulas.

[image]

Comment: thank you @EEM it works like a charm. You are a Star !!