# don't loose existing text formatting in cell when running VBA macro

Tags: excel, vba

Good day

I am running a macro to find the last one or more character(s) (do nothing is zero) after a dot and change their formatting in Bold and Red.
The issue I have now is this: the macro change formatting (Underlined) already present in some of the other part of the text in the cell.

for example "this is a test. 1" is underlined on the "is a test" part, and that is lost when the macro run to select after the dot and make it red and bold

[image: example]

**My question is:**
Is there is a way to protect the text formatting for being lost before applying formatting to the last part of the text via VBA ?

Below is the VBA Code that works very fine a part from that issue

```
    Sub Format_Text_In_Cells()
Dim Rng As Range, Cll As Range
Dim bLen As Byte, bPos As Byte

    Set Rng = Selection
    For Each Cll In Rng.Cells
        With Cll
            
            If Not (.HasFormula) Then           'Validates if cells contains a formula
            
                bLen = Len(.Value)                  'Get length of cell contents
                bPos = InStrRev(.Value, ".")        'Get position of last "."
                If bPos > 0 And bPos < bLen Then
                
                    With .Characters(Start:=1 + bPos, Length:=bLen).Font   'Use this line to exclude the `.`
                    'With .Characters(Start:=bPos, Length:=bLen).Font        'Use this line to include the `.`
                    
                        Rem Format Cell Contents
                        .FontStyle = "Bold"
                        .Superscript = False
                        .Color = XlRgbColor.rgbRed
    
    End With: End If: End If: End With: Next

    End Sub
```

I have discussed this in this post
[EXCEL VBA: Format text after Point in each Cell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66222837/excel-vba-format-text-after-point-in-each-cell/66225074#66225074)

Comment: Please could you accept the answer to your previous question if it helped you?

Comment: Basically you have to store the formatting info beforehand and reinstate it afterwards.